# rtl issue on ie

Tags: internet-explorer, hebrew, right-to-left

I am in development of hebrew website (with rtl direction of course). My page is working fine on firefox and chrome also safari. But i have no luck, my page is disorder when opening that on ie.

It is very helpful if any of you can give me suggestion or any other information to help me out from this issue.

Comment: Can you please give us a little bit code?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you are using IE6 ?

This great  tool may help you ...

http://ipinfo.info/netrenderer/

Online tool allowing to verify how websites appear in Microsoft Internet Explorer 5.5, 6 and 7.